# Future implementation in Swift 3

Tags: swift, functional-programming, closures, swift3, future

I am trying to implement a small future (promises) library with Swift 3 inspired by [this talk](https://github.com/JaviSoto/Talks#swift-summit-2015-back-to-the-futures) here is my implmentation :

```
public enum Result<T, E: Error> {
    case Success(T)
    case Error(E)
}

public struct Future<T, E: Error> {
    public typealias ResultType = Result<T, E>
    public typealias Completion = (ResultType) -> Void
    public typealias AsyncOperation = (Completion) -> Void

    private let operation: AsyncOperation

    public init(result: ResultType) {
        self.init(operation: { completion in
            completion(result)
        })
    }

    public init(value: T) {
        self.init(result: .Success(value))
    }

    public init(error: E) {
        self.init(result: .Error(error))
    }
    public init(operation: @escaping (Completion) -> Void) {
        self.operation = operation
    }

    public func start(completion: Completion) {
        self.operation() { result in
            completion(result)
        }
    }
}

//: ### Error handeling

enum UserInfoErrorDomain: Error {
    case UserDoesNotExist
    case UserRequestFailure
    case NetworkRequestFailure
}
```

and here is my usage:

```
func downloadFile(URL: NSURL) -> Future<NSData, UserInfoErrorDomain> {

    return Future(operation: { completion in
            DispatchQueue.main.async( execute: {
                print("Async2")
                let result: Result<NSData, UserInfoErrorDomain>

                if let data = NSData(contentsOf: URL as URL) {
                    result = Result.Success(data)
                }
                else {
                    result = Result.Error(.NetworkRequestFailure)
                }

                completion(result) // ERROR here Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape
            })
    })
}
```

but I get in the line of `completion(result)` and error of `Closure use of non-escaping parameter 'completion' may allow it to escape`

But the closure is already marked as `@escaping` in the method `public init(operation: @escaping (Completion) -> Void)` but maybe because it's a closure that takes a closure as argument and returns void needs another annotation, so to do that in Swift 3 because it seems that the code used to work in Swift 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [...] but maybe because it's a closure that takes a closure as argument and returns void needs another annotation [...]

You're  right. `Completion` is of type `(ResultType) -> Void`, which, as it's a parameter to your `AsyncOperation` function type, means that it's non-escaping by default – meaning that you cannot capture your `completion` parameter in an escaping closure (such as one passed to `DispatchQueue.main.async`).

Therefore you need to annotate `Completion` as `@escaping`:

```
public typealias AsyncOperation = (@escaping Completion) -> Void
```

and you'll want your `init(operation:)` and `start(completion:)` functions to look like this:

```
public init(operation: @escaping AsyncOperation) {
    self.operation = operation
}

// the completion: parameter needs to be escaping as it's going to be called after 
// an async operation has completed.
public func start(completion: @escaping Completion) {
    self.operation { result in
        completion(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried your suggestion but I have the same warning

Comment: @iOSGeek Please update the code in your question and I'll be happy to take a look :) You can also take a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/712de929e96966ee64760214de773caf) with my suggested fixes applied, which compiles fine.

Comment: this this the full code https://gist.github.com/tunidev/17a003cd03a315440c1b2f16eed50772 and thank you for the help in advance

Comment: @iOSGeek You didn't change `init(operation:)`'s parameter type to `@escaping AsyncOperation` as I suggested, meaning that `Completion` is non-escaping.